# Mautic : Incorrect IP Tracking

Tags: mautic

Mautic is not tracking individual IP addresses for visitors. It shows only 1 IP for all visitors.

162.241.252.242 - this is IP I see no matter where the visitor came from. I have even changed cloudflare settings to BYPASS the CACHE fro Mautic TRacking URL.

What else can i do? Any tips? I would love to track IPs of individual web visitors.

Thanks[image: Mautic Incorrect IP]

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a permanent solution, you can add `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP` to the array `$ipHolders` in line 92 of the file `/app/bundles/CoreBundle/Helper/IpLookupHelper.php`.

The array should look like this:

```
$ipHolders = [
    'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP',
    'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
    'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP',
    'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'HTTP_FORWARDED',
    'REMOTE_ADDR',
];
```

This will place `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP` as the first option when searching for the users' real IP address.